# Ask geolocation permission

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation

I'm trying to get user's geolocation in development environment. I believe I'm fulfilling every requirements, though I still don't see any prompt asking for my position.

Here's what I'm using:

- `navigator.geolocation`

> The Geolocation API is accessed via a call to `navigator.geolocation`; this will cause the user's browser to ask them for permission to access their location data.

- ngrok to have a SSL tunnel

> Secure context: This feature [Geolocation API] is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

- Firefox 99.0.1 (able to be located on other websites, no domain-specific rules)

---

`PermissionState` is always `prompt`, which mean a prompt is currently asking for the permission right ?

Am I missing something, or is there specific requirements when asking for localhost geolocation ?

Comment: More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation

Comment: See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I'd to call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback)` in order to have a prompt displayed.

If it can help anyone, here's my test code:

```js
// inside a Stimulus controller

connect() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition)
  } else {
    // I believe it may also mean geolocation isn't supported
    alert('Geolocation denied') 
  }
}

showPosition(position) {
  alert(`${position.coords.longitude} - ${position.coords.latitude}`)
}
```